# Button press not capturing correct Row status from DataGridView: how to reset or capture status?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Code works except for a bug: using the 'Modify' button, it gets the selected Row in a DataGridView and sends that data to ComboBoxes on a different Form if the left Column is clicked before the first column with data.

The issue arises if the user selects a cell in the DataGridView or doesn't select at all, which I have msgbox telling them to select row. When a Row is selected after that msgbox and the 'Modify' button is pressed again `DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count` does not seem to be picking it up and it still comes up blank.

Odd thing, 20% of the time it seems to work. How do I set it so that it checks the status and make sure it picks up the new selection?

Below is the code:

```
Private Sub Modify_BTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Modify_BTN.Click
    If (DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0) Then
        Dim newMod As New Mod_Form
        newMod.ChangeType = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(8).Value.ToString
        newMod.PartNum = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(9).Value.ToString
        newMod.PriorityT = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(10).Value.ToString
        newMod.DESC = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(11).Value.ToString
        newMod.Show()
    Else
        MsgBox("You did not select the row for the request from the data below, please select the row you want to modify.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the SelectionMode of your DGV? -- The SelectedRows indexing and CurrentRow don't necessarily have a relation. You can have a CurrentRow and `0` SelectedRows. Since you, apparently, only accept a single Row as input, why don't you simply get CurrentRow (checking whether it's null, of course)? -- You're showing that Form as non-modal: are you sure about that?

Comment: Jimi, Thanks on the non-modal, I actually didn't know that. As for SelectionMode, its set to RowHeaderSelect. I probably should look into all the properties but had no clue what SelectionMode even does. Is it just because I have it on the wrong SelectionMode? Thanks!

Comment: You can use whatever SelectionMode you want. Your code needs to consider it, tough. Maybe you want FullRowSelect instead. -- BTW, you should set a breakpoint in the first line of that method and check the related values. It's just a matter of debugging this code.

Comment: I changed it to 'FullRowSelect' and it seems to do what I need without issues. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: As mentioned, you don't want SelectedRows, you don't handle multiple Rows in your code. Just get `CurrentRow` if it's not `Nothing`.

Comment: I changed it to CurrentRow, when I press the "Modify" button at runtime, even though the first row is highlighted, it throws the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." How do I make it if the CurrentRow is Null, for it to msgbox that they need to select a row? It works fine if they select row, it only happens if form loads and they hit modify before selecting row. Thanks!

Comment: `if DataGridView1.CurrentRow IsNot Nothing Then [...] Else ' MessageBox.Show(...) End If`. How is that you have a null CurrentRow at that point? This should only happen when the DataGridView has no DataSource set.

Comment: Yeah, I honestly don't understand either, because the row is highlighted, Im just not sure why it is nothing considering, I thought by default it auto-selects the first row. Thank you so much for your time and effort in helping me.

Comment: Ok, I changed the code to what you posted, it seems to be working, let me test it out and will let you know if something else comes up. Thanks!